# Issues with performance of android with indeterminate progress bar

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have indeterminate progress bar, which is showed when I read data from internet. To show/gone progress bar I use its visibility. When I turn on option of progress bar, my app read data from net for 15 min, when I remove code of progress bar it lasts 20 s. It is possible that it makes my app so slow?

main_activity.xml:

```
<TableRow 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    >

    <ProgressBar
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxWidth="30dip"
     android:minWidth="30dip"
     android:maxHeight="30dip"
     android:minHeight="30dip"
     android:indeterminate="true"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/searchingInProgress" 
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        />

</TableRow>
```

1st fragment java code (this triggers connection to net by execute class FindSongTask, which inherit from ASyncTask):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText searchQueryField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchQueryField);
            String searchQuery = searchQueryField.getText().toString();

            if (searchQuery.length() > 0 && (currentQuery == null || !currentQuery.equals(searchQuery))) {
                new FindSongTask().execute(searchQuery);
                currentQuery = searchQuery;

                findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                v.setEnabled(false);

            }

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchQueryField.getWindowToken(), 0);



        }
    });

}
```

2nd fragment (this is executed after connection to net):

```
instance.findViewById(R.id.searchButton).setEnabled(true);
findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
super.onPostExecute(result);
```

Comment: It'd really help if you could share the relevant piece of code. Without having seen the code, all I can do is speculate. [This](http://www.example.com/) might be relevant to your query though.

Comment: Please post your code related to the ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    ProgressDialog pd;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
            //don't leak a window
        super.onPause();
        if(pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();
    }

    //no networking allowed on main thread
    private class NetworkingTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
        int result;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this,"","Display message...", true,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...strings){
            //perform networking here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused){
            //check result
            pd.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What did you edit? I don't see any changes... The way I showed you makes sure the window is only visible during the operation. AsyncTasks were made do handle the dialogs like this..